# PHP array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array filled with objects but I'm having a lot of difficulty getting the properties of the objects. I need to access individual properties.

Here is the `var_dump()`:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'CustShipToID' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'CustDesc' => null
      public 'Address1' => null
      public 'Address2' => null
      public 'City' => null
      public 'Phone' => null
      public 'State' => null
      public 'ZIP' => null
      public 'ArrivalDate' => string '2014-10-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'LoadDate' => string '2014-10-17 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'StopNum' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'ConfNum' => string '5143372' (length=7)
      public 'EVNum' => string '4409' (length=4)
      public 'ApptNum' => string '5pm' (length=3)
      public 'CarrId' => string '249' (length=3)
      public 'Temperature' => string '34' (length=2)
      public 'CarrDesc' => string 'JOHNY RAY TEST' (length=14)
      public 'LoadID' => string '1151' (length=4)
      public 'CustPOID' => string '4771' (length=4)
      public 'POBillToRef' => string '74312' (length=5)
      public 'POShipToRef' => string '' (length=0)
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'CustShipToID' => string '240' (length=3)
      public 'CustDesc' => string 'AMERICOLD, TAUNTON            ' (length=30)
      public 'Address1' => string '455 JOHN HANCOCK RD           ' (length=30)
      public 'Address2' => string '                      ' (length=22)
      public 'City' => string 'TAUNTON' (length=7)
      public 'Phone' => string '508-513-4409' (length=12)
      public 'State' => string 'MA' (length=2)
      public 'ZIP' => string '02780' (length=5)
      public 'ArrivalDate' => string '2014-10-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'LoadDate' => string '2014-10-17 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'StopNum' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'ConfNum' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'EVNum' => string '4409' (length=4)
      public 'ApptNum' => string '7am' (length=3)
      public 'CarrId' => string '249' (length=3)
      public 'Temperature' => string '34' (length=2)
      public 'CarrDesc' => string 'JOHNY RAY TEST' (length=14)
      public 'LoadID' => string '1151' (length=4)
      public 'CustPOID' => string '5176' (length=4)
      public 'POBillToRef' => string '51424' (length=5)
      public 'POShipToRef' => string '' (length=0)
```

Here is how I build my array:

```
$arr=array();
            for($i=0; ($i<count($custpo_ids)-1); $i++)
            {
                //echo $i." ".$custpo_ids[$i];
                $arr[] = array($report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i]));
            }
```

Here is my code to process the array:

```
for($y = 0; $y < count($arr); $y++){

                foreach($arr[$y] as $val){
                   //example property get
                    $val->EVNum;
                }
            }
```

Thoughts? The var dump is the right data, but somehow I'm trying to access it improperly.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump` on `$val` and see what you get. Also what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Twister1002 the var_dump is on $val. Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: What is returned when you do `$report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i])`? Is it another array? If it is another array, then it is a 3 dimensional array, and you are only going through 2 dimensions. So you would need to place another loop in your foreach statement to get the object

Comment: @Twister1002 it is another array

Comment: Then to get that object, you will need to go through another loop. Or, I would change `array($report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i]))` to `$report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i])`. Reason: It would only be 2 demintions. Since the pointer returns an array anyways, putting it into another array is kinda pointless, in my opinion.

Also `foreach` loops would be a better, easier way to get them.

Comment: Let me know if that works, and I will make it an answer.

Comment: @Twister1002 yeah you pointed me in the right direction. we can to the same solution. After I var_dumped `$report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i])` as you suggested it became apparent the second array was unnecessary. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, The reason you are no able to get your object is because your method `$report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i])` is returning an array. Causing `$arr` to be three dimensional and not two dimensional.

My Suggestion is to change this line

```
  $arr[] = array($report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i]));
```

to:

```
  $arr[] = $report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i]);
```

the `for` loops were only going through two dimensions and not three. That is why you obtained your error and could not use your object.

For going through your arrays, it may be easier to just use foreach loops and not for loops, as my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Your objects are in array *within* an array. So basically you're not going deep enough into your array to get those values:

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    foreach($element as $val){
        //example property get
        $val[0]->EVNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: Remove the second array where you build it: `$arr[] = $report_model->getBOLCustomerInfoII($custpo_ids[$i]);`. An array with a single object is kinda senseless.

Comment: @Waragi a function can only return a single object. If your function `getBOLCustomerInfoII()` returns one more than one object it will be in an array ... so your array is useless again.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Hm, I see. What I'm trying to do is build an array of objects and pass it to a formatter class for processing. I seem to be able to the build the array but not process it. getBOLCustomerInfoII($x) only returns one object per parameter, however it's in a for loop. It builds the array as it increments. I want to build that array and pass it. Am I doing things backwards?